# Convert json encoded String to json object in FosRestBundle

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I have a json encoded string in one of my DB fields, e.g.

[{"name":"car","price":"10"}]

I'm using the FosRestBundle to return the DB-Values in json format and the String above is returned - as String - nothing special until here;)

How can this String be converted, so that a Json Object is returned instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

My Entity contained this:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="options", type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $options;
```

"options" contained the json encoded string. So I tried it with the [JMS Serilizer Annotation @Accessor](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#accessor) and wrote this specific getter:

```
/**
 * Get optionsAsArray
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getOptionsAsArray()
{
    return (array)json_decode($this->options, true);
}
```

Still got an error "Array to string conversion". So the Solution was, to add another Annotation [@type](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#type) and the JMSSerializer returned nicely formatted JSON.

This is what the Entity has to look like:

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Accessor;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Type;


/* ... */

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="options", type="string", nullable=true)
 * @Accessor(getter="getOptionsAsArray")
 * @Type("array")
 */
private $options;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can decode this string to an stdClass or an associative array with [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php). Is this what you are looking for?

EDIT : This should work

```
public function myAction()
{
    // do stuff
    $string = '[{"name":"car","price":"10"}]';
    $array = json_decode($string, true);

    /* array is like
    [
      0 => [
        'name' => string(3) "car"
        'price' => string(2) "10"
      ]
    ]
    */

    return $array;
}
```

Comment: I tried json_decode but then the resulting Object or Array is returned as String to0 (content of the variable is just "Array", where I expected the array values transformed to a json_object

Comment: But "json_object" means nothing. A "JSON object" like you say is a string formatted with the json notation.